# Strange Charset behaviour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

So, I have a very strange String behaviour. First thin is I fetch the String from the internet and decode it as UTF-8. Everything fine sofar.

```js
request.get(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
  body = iconv.decode(new Buffer(body), "ISO-8859-1");
  body = body.replace(/"/g, "");
  parseData(body);
});
```

I then parse this data (CSV) and try to compare it:

```js
if (record[40] == "Dismantling") {
  console.log("push");
  output.push(record);

}
```

This simple comparison should eventually work, yes there is a string Dismantling at some point.

I have tried multiple things and have figure the following:

```js
console.log("Length "+ record[40].length + " " + "Dismantling".length)
//result is "Length 23 11"
```

So the parsed string is 23, the manually entered string is 11! Weird.

When Looping through  record[40].charCodeAt(i) I get something like this:

0 68 0 105 0 115 0 109 0 97 0 110 0 116 0 108 0 105 0 110 0 103 0

While Dismantling returns:

68 105 115 109 97 110 116 108 105 110 103

So the question is, why do I have those 0??? And How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you positive that your server returns ISO-8859-1 so that you have to decode it?

Comment: nope. And I just figured it out. It returns  "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators"